# Difficulties with std::map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, std

Edit:
The data is as follows

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<T> Resource;
typedef std::map<std::string, Resource> ResourceMap;
```

This is the function

```
const T& Get(const std::string& key)
{
    ResourceMap::iterator itr = mResources.find(key);
    return (itr != mResources.end()) ? itr->second : mDefault;

}
```

Error:

```
Error   1   error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'sf::Texture' to 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>'  d:\sanity\trunk\client\src\assetmanager.h   28
```

Also I'm creating an object like that :

```
AssetManager<sf::Texture> imgManager;
```

Okay, sorry for missing information, I was in a rush.

The only problem left is :

```
return (itr != mResources.end()) ? itr->second.get() : mDefault;
```

get() returns raw pointer and I need to return reference to what the shared_ptr is pointing.

How should I do that?

Comment: what is the type of mResources?

Comment: Could you show the declaration of `mResources`?

Comment: So I guess `T` and `Resource` are of the same type?

Comment: You are giving us very incomplete information (which could explain the `-1` for your question), so must guess a lot. For example, we must guess the `Get` function is a method of `AssetManager<T>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Error   1   error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'sf::Texture' to
'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>' d:\sanity\trunk\client\src\assetmanager.h 28
```

I guess your problem is that `itr->second` is of one type (`Resource`, if your `std::map` typedef is correct), while `mDefault` must be something other.

The ternary operator cannot handle the two different types, so you must correct your code to be sure both items left and right of the `:` part of the `?:` operator are of the same type (or compatible ones).

So confirm this, I need:

- the declaration of the `Resource` type
- the declaration of the `T` type
- the declaration of the `mDefault` member variable

### Edit

Let's assume you have something like:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<T> Resource;
typedef std::map<std::string, Resource> ResourceMap;

template <typename T>
class AssetManager
{
    const T& Get(const std::string& key)
    {
        ResourceMap::iterator itr = mResources.find(key);
        return (itr != mResources.end()) ? itr->second : mDefault;
    }

    ResourceMap mResources ;
    ??? mDefault ;

    // etc.
} ;
```

instanciated like:

```
AssetManager<sf::Texture> imgManager;
```

Now, I need the type of `mDefault` to continue.

My guess: You MUST make sure your code is more like:

```
    const T& Get(const std::string& key) const
    {
        ResourceMap::const_iterator itr = mResources.find(key);
        return (itr != mResources.end()) ? *(itr->second) : *(mDefault);
    }

    ResourceMap mResources ;
    Resource mDefault ;
```

As you want to return the `Resource`, not the shared_ptr of the `Resource`.

Note that I added `const` keywords/prefix to be consistent with the `const` return

### Edit 2

As you have:

```
    ResourceMap mResources ;
    T mDefault ;
```

So I guess you should write:

```
    const T& Get(const std::string& key) const
    {
        ResourceMap::const_iterator itr = mResources.find(key);
        return (itr != mResources.end()) ? *(itr->second) : mDefault;
    }
```

`itr->second` is a smart pointer, so if you want to get the pointer object, you simply need to dereference the smart pointer: `*(itr->second)`.

As for returning a reference to mDefault, this is indicated by the function's return type `const T &`, so you don't need anything more.

Comment: Right now itr->second.get() is of type sf::Texture* how would I convert it to sf:Texture& ?

Comment: T is sf::Texture
mDefault is T

Comment: Well, thanks, that error is gone, but :


Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>' to 'std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree>' d:\sanity\trunk\client\src\assetmanager.h 27